# PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet Multiple worksheet not working

Tags: php, spreadsheet, xlsx, phpoffice

The following code is working only when I comment the Thrid sheet, I can see open and view the content which inserted, but when I include the Third sheet, it doesn't open the file but showing error,`can’t be opened for some reason.`.

```
    $this->spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet;
    $this->spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    $sheet = $this->spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
    $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello world');
    $sheet->setTitle('First');

    $this->spreadsheet->createSheet();
    $this->spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(1);
    $sheet = $this->spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
    $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello');
    $sheet->setTitle('Second');

    $this->spreadsheet->createSheet();
    $this->spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(2);
    $sheet = $this->spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
    $sheet->setTitle('Third');


    $writer = new Xlsx($this->spreadsheet);
    $writer->setOffice2003Compatibility(true);
    $writer->save($fileName);
```

Please help me to solve this. https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/
(develop) branch

Answer (score 0):

Arcording to [documentation](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/worksheets/#adding-a-new-worksheet) you can try this:

```
$reader =  \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader("Xlsx");

$spreadsheet = $reader->load('<path>'); //Path of reader sheet    
// Create a new worksheet called "Name" in your case 3 Times
$myWorkSheet = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Worksheet($spreadsheet, 'Name');

// Attach the "Name" worksheet as the first worksheet in the Spreadsheet object
$spreadsheet->addSheet($myWorkSheet, 0);
```

Then you can call a sheet by name

```
$spreadsheet->getSheetByName('Name');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting or commenting out the line

```
$writer->setOffice2003Compatibility(true);
```

it was throwing that error in my case